# Filling an arc when using relative coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a problem filling arcs when I'm using relative coordinates. As you can see in the graphic below the filling starts horizontally (for the upper beta). For the upper alpha I could "solve" this problem with an ugly method by instead of using realtive coordinates I just typed in an approximated value for the radius so one can hardly detect it.

I commented the problematic parts in the TikZ-Code below. Also, on a side note, I'm unhappy with the "below" positioning of the upper beta.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\filldraw[draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20] (0,0)--(.7,0) arc (0:30:.7cm);
% I want the line before drawing the arc to be .7cm long without having to use 5.36 as a coordinate
\filldraw[draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20] (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--(30:5.36) arc (210:240:.7cm);

\filldraw[draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20] (3.5,0)--(2.8,0) arc (180:60:.7cm);
\filldraw[draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20] (3.5,0)--(4.2,0) arc (0:60:.7cm);

\filldraw[draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20] (7,0)--(6.3,0) arc (180:120:.7cm);
% If I use a relative coordinate for the desired arc I can't fill it the way I want
\filldraw[draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20] (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})++(-60:.7) arc (300:240:.7cm);

\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={180:A}] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={0:B}] (B) at (7,0) {};
\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={90:C}] (C) at (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2}) {};
\draw (0,0)-- 
    node[midway, below]{r} 
    node[above, pos=.15, green!50!black]{$\alpha$}(3.5,0)
    node[above, pos=.95, red!50!black]{$\gamma$}-- 
    node[midway, below]{r}node[above, pos=.1, orange!50!black]{$\delta$}node[above, pos=.9,         blue!50!black]{$\beta$}(7,0)--
    % What am I doing wrong with the following label distance for beta? 1cm should be way off
    node[below, pos=.95, blue!50!black, label distance=1cm]{$\beta$}(30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--
    node[below, pos=.07, green!50!black]{$\alpha$}(0,0);

\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={-90:M}] (D) at (3.5,0) {};
\draw (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--node[midway, below]{r} (3.5,0);
\draw[dashed, black!60] (7,0) arc (0:180:3.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is because of the `++` which does not add a path but just move the coordinate. You can do `\filldraw[draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20] (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})++(-60:.7) arc (300:240:.7cm)
--(30:{7*sqrt(3)/2});` but it may be much simpler to use the `angles` library here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes from `++` which does not add a path but just move the coordinate. If you only want to repair the code, make sure that the arc gets continued to the corner.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\filldraw[draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20] (0,0)--(.7,0) arc (0:30:.7cm);
% I want the line before drawing the arc to be .7cm long without having to use 5.36 as a coordinate
\filldraw[draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20] (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--(30:5.36) arc (210:240:.7cm);

\filldraw[draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20] (3.5,0)--(2.8,0) arc (180:60:.7cm);
\filldraw[draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20] (3.5,0)--(4.2,0) arc (0:60:.7cm);

\filldraw[draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20] (7,0)--(6.3,0) arc (180:120:.7cm);
% If I use a relative coordinate for the desired arc I can't fill it the way I want
\filldraw[draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20] (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})++(-60:.7) arc (300:240:.7cm)
--(30:{7*sqrt(3)/2});

\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={180:A}] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={0:B}] (B) at (7,0) {};
\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={90:C}] (C) at (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2}) {};
\draw (0,0)-- 
    node[midway, below]{r} 
    node[above, pos=.15, green!50!black]{$\alpha$}(3.5,0)
    node[above, pos=.95, red!50!black]{$\gamma$}-- 
    node[midway, below]{r}node[above, pos=.1,orange!50!black]{$\delta$}
    node[above, pos=.9,blue!50!black]{$\beta$}(7,0)--
    % What am I doing wrong with the following label distance for beta? 1cm should be way off
    node[below, pos=.95, blue!50!black, label distance=1cm]{$\beta$}(30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--
    node[below, pos=.07, green!50!black]{$\alpha$}(0,0);

\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={-90:M}] (D) at (3.5,0) {};
\draw (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--node[midway, below]{r} (3.5,0);
\draw[dashed, black!60] (7,0) arc (0:180:3.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would rather use the `angles` and `quotes` libraries (and use math mode for `A` etc.). You can set the radius of the angles with a key, allows you to adjust much more easily. Also you can use a style for the fills since it is repeating (up to the color).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,label distance=.1cm,angle radius=1cm,
    pft/.style={draw=#1!50!black, fill=#1!20}]
  \path[draw] (0,0) coordinate[label={180:$A$}] (A) 
   -- (7,0) coordinate[label={0:$B$}] (B)  
   -- (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2}) coordinate[label={90:$C$}] (C)  
   -- cycle
   (C) -- (3.5,0) coordinate[label={-90:$M$}] (D)
   pic[pft=green,"$\alpha$"]{angle=A--C--D}
   pic[pft=green,"$\alpha$"]{angle=D--A--C}
   pic[pft=blue,"$\beta$"]{angle=D--C--B}
   pic[pft=blue,"$\beta$"]{angle=C--B--D}
   pic[pft=red,"$\gamma$"]{angle=C--D--A}
   pic[pft=orange,"$\delta$"]{angle=B--D--C}
   (A) edge["$r$"'] (D)
   (D) edge["$r$"'] (C)
   (D) edge["$r$"'] (B);
  \draw[dashed, black!60] (7,0) arc (0:180:3.5cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is why I do advocate automatic solutions here:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\tikzset{pft/.style={draw=#1!50!black, fill=#1!20}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {40,50,...,140,130,120,...,50}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,label distance=.1cm,angle radius=1cm,angle
eccentricity=0.75]
  \path[draw] (-3.5,0) coordinate[label={180:$A$}] (A) 
   -- (3.5,0) coordinate[label={0:$B$}] (B)  
   -- (\X:3.5) coordinate[label={90:$C$}] (C)  
   -- cycle
   (C) -- (0,0) coordinate[label={-90:$M$}] (D)
   pic[pft=green,"$\alpha$"]{angle=A--C--D}
   pic[pft=green,"$\alpha$"]{angle=D--A--C}
   pic[pft=blue,"$\beta$"]{angle=D--C--B}
   pic[pft=blue,"$\beta$"]{angle=C--B--D}
   pic[pft=red,"$\gamma$"]{angle=C--D--A}
   pic[pft=orange,"$\delta$"]{angle=B--D--C}
   (A) edge["$r$"'] (D)
   (D) edge["$r$"'] (C)
   (D) edge["$r$"'] (B);
  \draw[dashed, black!60] (3.5,0) arc (0:180:3.5cm); 
  \path (0,4); %<- only for animation
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see. That's very interesting.
Do you mind also clarifying what I asked in the 3rd comment? How does the "label distance" command exactly work? I tried different values but the positioning of the beta didnt change at all.

Comment: @Buh I wouldn't use `label distance` to fix the position of the labels. But `label distance` has no effect on nodes, which is why `1cm` does not give you anything.

Comment: I see. I now just added the node manually via "\path (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})++(270:.2) node[below, blue!50!black]{$\beta$};"

Comment: @Buh I personally would use the `angles` library here. Or, at least, make sure that the angle labels are nicely centered, which you can achieve e.g. with the `calc` library. That is, you can measure the angle and put the node accordingly. Yet this is essentially what the `angles` library does.

Comment: I haven't worked with the angles library. But isn't the following the same? I know the parameters of the angles since I drew them with the arc command. For example, I know that gamma is essentially a sector with radius .7cm and angle 120°. So I can use a path to get from the center (3.5,0) of the sector to the middle  of the angle via ++(120:.35) and then place the node there?

Comment: @Buh Yes, you know the angles in your example. So what you are saying is true. But the issue is that whenever you change something in your setup, you would have to go back and change all the hard coded angles. This is why libraries like `calc` and `angles` are convenient: they spare you from this. You can change the setup, e.g. the location of the corner `C`, and it will still give you the right output.

Answer (score 6):

[image: screenshot]

By replacing `++` with `--++`, it works.

```
\filldraw[draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20] (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--++(-60:.7) arc (300:240:.7cm);%<--- replace ++ by --++
```

Concerning the beta label, you can slightly modify your code by placing the label a little to the left and below:

```
node[below,xshift=-5pt, pos=.93, blue!50!black, label distance=1cm]{$\beta$}(30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})
```

---

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5]

\filldraw[draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20] (0,0)--(.7,0) arc (0:30:.7cm);
% I want the line before drawing the arc to be .7cm long without having to use 5.36 as a coordinate
\filldraw[draw=green!50!black, fill=green!20] (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--(30:5.36) arc (210:240:.7cm);

\filldraw[draw=red!50!black, fill=red!20] (3.5,0)--(2.8,0) arc (180:60:.7cm);
\filldraw[draw=orange!50!black, fill=orange!20] (3.5,0)--(4.2,0) arc (0:60:.7cm);

\filldraw[draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20] (7,0)--(6.3,0) arc (180:120:.7cm);
% If I use a relative coordinate for the desired arc I can't fill it the way I want
\filldraw[draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20] (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--++(-60:.7) arc (300:240:.7cm);%<--- replace ++ by --++

\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={180:A}] (A) at (0,0) {};
\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={0:B}] (B) at (7,0) {};
\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={90:C}] (C) at (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2}) {};
\draw (0,0)-- 
    node[midway, below]{r} 
    node[above, pos=.15, green!50!black]{$\alpha$}(3.5,0)
    node[above, pos=.95, red!50!black]{$\gamma$}-- 
    node[midway, below]{r}node[above, pos=.1, orange!50!black]{$\delta$}node[above, pos=.9,         blue!50!black]{$\beta$}(7,0)--
    % What am I doing wrong with the following label distance for beta? 1cm should be way off
    node[below,xshift=-5pt, pos=.93, blue!50!black, label distance=1cm]{$\beta$}(30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})(30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--
    node[below, pos=.07, green!50!black]{$\alpha$}(0,0);

\node[label distance=.1 cm, label={-90:M}] (D) at (3.5,0) {};
\draw (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2})--node[midway, below]{r} (3.5,0);
\draw[dashed, black!60] (7,0) arc (0:180:3.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I like that solution! This also easily fixed what gave me trouble with the upper alpha angle.

Comment: Well, that's just another way to continue the arc to the corner....

Comment: This does not continue the arc to the corner.

Comment: @AndréC Very very nice all the answer for the question.

Comment: Of course it does, just on the other side.

Comment: No, he starts from the corner, then draws the arc of the circle without returning to his starting point (the corner).

Comment: Yes, this is what is called a continuation of a path. One can continue on both sides, of course.

Comment: Not at all, nothing changed to the path given in the question.

Answer (score 3):

`angles` library can make this job easier.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, angle radius=1cm]

% coordinates 
\coordinate[label distance=.1 cm, label={180:A}] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label distance=.1 cm, label={-90:M}] (M) at (3.5,0);
\coordinate[label distance=.1 cm, label={0:B}] (B) at (7,0);
\coordinate[label distance=.1 cm, label={90:C}] (C) at (30:{7*sqrt(3)/2});

% angles 
\pic [pic text=$\beta$, draw=blue!50!black, fill=blue!20] {angle=M--C--B};
\pic [pic text=$\beta$, draw=blue!50!black,fill=blue!20] {angle=C--B--M};
\pic [pic text=$\alpha$,draw=green!50!black,fill=green!20] {angle=M--A--C};
\pic [pic text=$\alpha$,draw=green!50!black,fill=green!20] {angle=A--C--M};
\pic [pic text=$\delta$,draw=green!50!orange,fill=orange!20] {angle=B--M--C};
\pic [pic text=$\gamma$,draw=red!50!black,fill=red!20] {angle=C--M--A};

% paths to connect the coordinates 
\draw (A) --  node[midway, below]{r} (M) --  node[midway, below]{r} (B)-- (C)-- (A)
  (M) --  node[midway, below]{r} (C);
\draw[dashed, black!60] (B) arc (0:180:3.5cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1, but as long as you reduce the code, you might as well use styles like `every pic/.style={angle radius=1cm}`

Comment: @AndréC thanks for the feedback. made that change .